# SQL Select using combination of values from row in different table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

Hard to explain in the title. Newb here.

I have a temp table with 2 columns.

```
| numdoc | linha |
| 1      |  5    |
| 233423 |  7    |
| 34663  |  4    |
```

Now I need to use these values to make a select like this:

```
select *
from wgcdoclinhas
where numdoc in (numdoc from #temptable) 
  and linagrup (linha from #temptable)
```

And I'd like for this to return rows where the values match the ones from the #temptable but without mixing values. Because the query as I wrote it doesn't make that distinction. There is only one result per row to be had.

As in, I have 300 rows in my #temptable and the result I want is 300 rows to be shown.

My desired result for the query ran on the above #temptable would show 3 rows, one for each of the #temptable.

- 1 result for where numdoc=1 and linagrup=5,
- another for numdoc=233423 and lnagrup=7
- and finally another for numdoc=34663 and linagrup=4

I understand if this isn't clear enough, hopefully it is.

Thanks.

Comment: would be easy to understand if you include a sample data with desire output. Specially we dont know what is on wgcdoclinhas table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply join temporary table to your table and you will get the results that you need:

```
select w.*
from wgcdoclinhas w 
inner join #temptable t
    on w.numdoc = t.numdoc AND w.linha = t.linha
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be solved if you use JOIN query.

```
SELECT A.numdoc,A.numdoc 
FROM wgcdoclinhas A,#temptable T
WHERE A.numdoc = T.numdoc AND A.linha = T.linha
```